# SQL union or join

Tags: sql, join, union

You have a list of 2.0 million IDs in Table A. You have another list of 3.5 million IDs in Table B. Some customer IDs show up multiple times in each table and some IDs show up in both tables. Which of the following would you use to create (in one step - no subqueries) a Table C that contains a list of distinct (no duplicates) customer IDs present in either Table A, Table B, or both?

Union, Union ALL, Outer Join, Union Join-?

Comment: What have *you* tried?

Comment: I tried select ids from table A outer join table B on A.id=B.id.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT ROW. But being that you'd need a union to return both tables into one field, not sure DISTINCT ROW would work.

Comment: Please clarify via post edits, not comments. Please read [ask] & the downvote arrow mouseover text.

Answer (score 0):

Union is a SET operation (in SQL and otherwise in mathematics in the field of set theory).  A set is a collection of distinct items.  Like a list that does not contain any duplicates.  A UNION of sets is the combination of all the distinct items in one or more lists.

So in SQL, the UNION function will combine all of its parameters and return a SET of unique values in the combined list.

Comment: Got it, Thanks so much for your reply.